# How to disable one responsive view from getbootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using getbootstrap for building my website. According to my design, I don't want to show the portrait view of tablets. How can I eliminate this?

I just want iPad landscape and desktop normal, iPhone portrait and landscape. How can I eliminate all other views?

Comment: Are you using the full package or did you customize it? And are you using the JavaScript included with it?

Comment: @Gab I'm using the full package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to customise the screen width values under the section  *Media queries breakpoints* in http://getbootstrap.com/customize/.

This will then generate one or more custom CSS files that you can add to your site.

You will of course have to specify the correct values for iPads and iPhones with or without Retina displays. This should help:

http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

The bad news is that you may have to hack the CSS generated from getbootstrap.com in order to set the media breakpoints explicitly for Retina devices using `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2`.